# CSS Footer will not move down the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS:

```
body,html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    font-family:Calibri;
    position: relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important; 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto -580px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}

.push {
    height: 100px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

/* header stuff */
#header-topbar {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color:#a79494;
}
#phone-tel {
    position:block;
    float:right;
    margin-right:16%;
    margin-top:5px;
    font-size:20px;
}
#logo {
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    margin-left:15%;
    margin-top:-20px;
}

/* main body/content */
#body-content {
    width:70%;
    margin:120px auto 0 auto;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border:solid 1px #a79494;
    border-top:solid 4px #a2cd3a;
}

/*footer */
```

for my website, for some reason the footer won't go down the bottom of the page.

I have tried adding the Push `div` to make it move down to the bottom of the page but that didn't work for some reason.

Any ideas what I can do? I have created a fiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/cGGMS/

Comment: might be something to do with that -580px margin?

Comment: sidenote: all those scrollbars are intended? looks horrible imho. the neg. wrapper margin seems to act faulty.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the negative margin of `#wrap` like this :

```
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important; 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cGGMS/2/

Answer (score 1):

`#wrap`'s margin must be `0 auto -100px`

http://jsfiddle.net/cGGMS/3/

"the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height"
Your footer's height is 100px

Comment: ah yes - that worked ok
do you know why the footer is displaying off the page - i have to scroll down to see it. can it be just at the bottom of the page http://jsfiddle.net/cGGMS/7/

Comment: because you're viewing it in jsfiddle :)

Comment: i mean if i display it in internet explorer the footer displays right at the bottom and i have to scroll. its as if there is something above the footer and below the body-content div that is pushing it down but there is nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try using the styles `postition:fixed;` and `bottom:0;` on your footer.

Comment: i dont want the footer fixed, just needs to be under all the content but displaying at the bottom of the page

Comment: In which case, try using floats for the content and then `clear:both;` on the footer itself.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt close the wrap div properly. it should be closed after the footer div . here is the working code http://jsfiddle.net/cGGMS/4/

```
   <div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-inner">
          &copy; Copyright <?php echo date("Y"); ?> All Rights Reserved.<br /><br />
     </div>
  </div>
  </div> <!--wrap should end here not at the top of footer -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Please comment this line and use this.

```
#wrap {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important; 
height: 100%; 
/* margin: 0 auto -580px; */
```

}